# Use of combination CAFCI and GFCI breakers instead of recepticles

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, gfci, afci

I am about to begin a project that will include one or two new circuit for outdoor lights and receptacles attached to the main building. I will probably installing a new *home run* line from the panel for this circuit.

Is there any reason **not** to use a combination CAFCI/GFCI breaker instead of specialized receptacles, other than price (which is fairly inconsequential for one or two circuits)?

If these breakers are used, am I free to use all standard receptacles downstream (with appropriate outdoor covers as applicable)?

There are no shared neutrals planned for these circuits.

Comment: Why do you need/want AFCI protection outdoors??

Comment: I certainly value GFCI protection outdoors. Outdoor equipment is more likely to get wet, is more likely to be used in a situation where I am well earthed, etc. The risk is at least as high as in a kitchen or bathroom.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey My understanding is that CAFCI helps protect against arcing in walls and boxes that could start a fire. My exterior walls (on which the exterior fixtures and receptacles are mounted) are no more fireproof than my interior ones. Also, the combo units only cost about $10 more than the straight GFCIs.

Comment: Combination arc fault protection does NOT provide the protection that is required where gfci protection is needed.

Comment: @user24125 There are combination breakers that provide CAFCI and GFCI protection, as well as amperage overload protection. Those are the ones I am considering.

Comment: Thing is, you have to find them. They are not sitting on shelves yet at the big box stores, and no supply houses I know carry them yet. I'm sure the internet is the solution to this though but those of us who do this everyday typically don't buy like that.

Comment: @keshlam, I don't think anyone was questioning GFI protection. It's been required for ages outdoors so it's kind of a non-issue.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey Big box offering them [special order](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-by-Schneider-Electric-QO-20-Amp-Single-Pole-Dual-Function-CAFCI-and-GFCI-Circuit-Breaker-QO120DFC/204844647)

Comment: A regular gfci outlet or breaker is designed to open the circuit between 4 to 6 mA .I've read that a cafci breakers gfci function doesn't react within this range and therefor does not take the place of regular gfci protection. Maybe they make one now that does. You should check the technical specifications on your cafci breaker before you try to use it for gfci protection by itself.

Comment: By the way the nec does not require cafci protection for outdoor receptacles-yet

Comment: I wasn't able to find any spec sheets online, for the breaker you're looking at. user24125 is right though, make sure you check the documentation to insure proper GFCI protection. Some combination AFCI devices only offer "*Ground-Fault Protection of Equipment*", which allows a higher fault current than "*Ground-Fault Protection of Personnel*" devices. *Ground-Fault Protection of Equipment* devices trip around 30mA or higher, whereas *Ground-Fault Protection of Personnel* devices trip between 4-6mA.

Comment: @Tester101 The listing at [Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-by-Schneider-Electric-QO-20-Amp-Single-Pole-Dual-Function-CAFCI-and-GFCI-Circuit-Breaker-QO120DFC/204844647?N=5yc1vZbm0kZ1z0x9jp) says *Class A* for GFCI which should mean 6 mA, correct?

Comment: @bib -- Class A is indeed equivalent to the Code's "ground fault protection for personnel" aka tripping at the 4-6mA mark.

Answer (score 3):

Nuisance trips are generally easier to reset at a receptacle than in the breaker box.

Comment: Not true.  The panel is a one stop shop. Receptacles are scattered about, and may require searching to find the one that's tripped.

Comment: I'm with @Zhentar. I'd much rather have the GFI at the point of use rather than at the panel. AFCIs we don't have much choice these days.

Comment: The panel is a one stop shop but might also be labeled poorly/incorrectly, and it also might be out in a garage or in a basement when you're doing something that is really inconvenient to stop. Convenience is the entire point that being able to reset at the receptacle serves.

Answer (score 0):

A location that requires combination arc fault protection and gfci protection needs both. CAFCI breakers do not provide the gfci protection required by the NEC. A gfci needs to open the circuit with a ground fault between 4 mA to 6mA to provide the required protection. A cafci may not react at this level read the specifications to see if yours does.

Comment: The type of breaker he is referring to *does* provide ground-fault protection for personnel -- the emerging common name for it is a DFCI -- Dual-Function Circuit Interruptor.